# Flash for Android AIR - Mousewheel doesn't respond

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, mousewheel

I am working on an application in flash 5.5 AS3 for deployment on an android tablet through AIR. The App uses an external Bluetooth mouse connected to the android device. When the Apllication is run on PC the mouse wheel detects satisfactory values when scrolled. But when the apk is deployed on android tablet, there is no response to the mouse wheel scroll in the application. The left click behaves as expected. Even the middle click and right click behave as the left click!

The mouse wheel as well as all left right and middle button work well in other apps.

Here is my code -

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL,Wheel);
function Wheel(e:MouseEvent):void
{
        mytext.text = e.delta.toString(); 
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: I'm thinking you would need to create an ANE for ongenericmotionlistener

Comment: I abandoned Flash altogether. Despite Flash design environment being much superior

Comment: Same. Haven't touched flash in forever.